# Why does Latté = LattÃ©?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

I have a webform and an input if you put in Latté and `POST` it using JSON...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://"+document.domain+"/includes/rpc.php",
    data: {method:"add_item",item:item},    
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 10000,
    success:......
```

`item` will be the value `Latté` Latté is posted and the responding JSON is `Latt\u00e9` which the browser interprets as `Latté`. Effectively this script is a WYSIWYG editor so what you type in you get back. Anyhue if I refresh the text is pulled out of mysql and comes out as `LattÃ©?`. So I am guessing that MYSQL is not the correct collation?

Some more information - the query to edit the DB is

`UPDATE menu_items SET description =  'Latté' WHERE item_id = '742'`

the JSON reply is

`{"description":"Latt\u00e9","id":"#recordsArray_742"}`

Comment: Looks like the (HTML) page encoding is just set wrong. Try setting it to UTF-8.

Comment: More specifically, everything needs to be the correct character set/encoding.  The database table (column specifically), the connection to the database, and the webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be precise, the collation is the way in which the strings are compared and sorted. It has a relationship with the character set, but **your problem is an character set problem**, not a collation problem.

> [A character set is a set of symbols and encodings. A collation is a set of rules for comparing characters in a character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-general.html).

The first thing that you've to know is **which character set you're using**. Are you using UTF-8 or LATIN1 or others?

After that I'd try to **output the correct header** from the PHP script generating the JSON string. For example for UTF-8:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

This could already solve your problem, if it doesn't we have to look deeper on **how do you connect to the DB** and how you manipulate your data. Let me know in case which MySQL libraries or framework are you using to connect to the db, and post the relevant source code.

Comment: Added mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbh); to connection, problem solved. Thx

Answer (score 2):

It could be MySQL's collation.

It could also be HTTP encoding.

Or you could be using string functions in PHP which are not multi-byte-safe.

This kind of error can happen at many points through your tool chain.

Answer (score 0):

Either the database collation is wrong or the DBAL you are using (PDO?).

Answer (score 0):

Use utf8_encode() around your fetched values in your PHP backend before you output it